# Multiple Neo4j databases from single instance

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

As documented in many places, older versions didnt allow to have multiple databases in single instance. As in have separate `/db/data` location per database.

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/266#issuecomment-78454814),

> Neo4j 2.2 will be a first step in that direction.

I currently have `Neo4j 2.3.3`. Does the newer versions support this feature yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. Best way to manage multiple databases side by side on the same machine is using containers such as Docker - you can pick up the latest GA version of Neo4j on DockerHub. If you look at the latest 3.0 milestone (beta), you'll see a number of improvements, including changes to directory structure & config, to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You don't need docker. See my answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58751637/3209523

setting up docker with neo4j is hard and cumbersome due to many volumes and ports

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 - You can now use the DozerDB plugin which enables multi-database functionality, among other enterprise features in 4.x and 5.x versions of Neo4j Community Edition.

See:  https://dozerdb.org and https://github.com/dozerdb/